# Can I re-apply my edit?

Tags: discussion, support

The following edit:

https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/9841947

was rejected because it allegedly defaces a question that directly references the project I am adding a tag for. Given that this is clearly wrong, what can I do?

Comment: Reviewers cannot be expected to be domain experts, to someone without experience on the topic it may seem that you were adding in irrelevant information. Best thing to do in this case would probably be to enlist the help of a > 2k rep user, head over to chat and see if anyone has experience on the subject and agrees.

Comment: You know, your edit-summary is *worse than useless*: Use it to motivate/justify your edit, not to do it twice. Also, if you know that project, consider reading the [tag-wiki excerpt help-page](http://stackoverflow.com/help/tag-excerpts), and add tag-wiki and excerpt.

Comment: @Deduplicator: thanks, it's just that I assumed that the summary wouldn't be needed anyway because it's a trivial change. I just added a tag excerpt here: https://stackoverflow.com/tags/american-fuzzy-lop/info

Comment: @Mogsdad applied my edit, thanks for help!